# Typescript - How to preserve signature of parameters in a function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following function:

```
const fn = (...args: any[]): any[] {
    ...
    return args;
};

fn(1, "string", true) //-> [1, "string", true]: any[]
```

This implementation currently outputs `any[]`.

Is there any signature that would allow `fn` to output the actual types I passed in, in the same order instead of `any[]`?
Basically I would like to keep the signature of my params in the output:

```
fn(1, "string", true)   //-> [1, "string", true]: [number, string, boolean]
fn("string", 1)         //-> ["string", 1]: [string, number]
fn("string", 1, true)   //-> [false, 1, true]: [boolean, number, boolean]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after playing around with different signatures I was finally able to achieve it with this signature:

```
const fn = <T extends any[]>(...deps: T): T => ...
```

please let me know if there's a better way